# What is the fastest way to count the number of MySql rows left after a limited results query

Tags: mysql

If I have a mysql limited query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > '2020-12-12' LIMIT 1,16;
```

Is there a faster way to check and see how many results are left after my limit?

I was trying to do a count with limit, but that wasn't working, i.e.

```
SELECT count(ID) AS count FROM my_table WHERE date > '2020-12-12' LIMIT 16,32;
```

The ultimate goal here is just to determine if there ARE any other rows to be had beyond the current result set, so if there is another faster way to do this that would be fine too.

Comment: Does it need to be a single MySQL command or could you perhaps do a simple stored procedure where you do and IF/Then to check the UBOUND of the array and then have it decide to do one thing (the default thing when its under the limit) and use the ELSE for beyond your set limit to do something else, such create another select to do an inverse to find excluded records.

Comment: I might be under-thinking this, but can't you just use `SELECT count(ID) - 32 AS count FROM my_table WHERE date > '2020-12-12';` to subtract the number of results you've already retrieved?

Comment: @yoniLavi  Your overthinking was my underthinking.   So obvious.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to do this by counting the rows:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM my_table WHERE date > '2020-12-12'
```

That tells you how many total rows match the condition. Then you can compare that to the size of the result you got with your query using LIMIT. It's just arithmetic.

Past versions of MySQL had a function `FOUND_ROWS()` which would report how many rows would have matched if you didn't use `LIMIT`. But it turns out this had *worse* performance than running two queries, one to count rows and one to do your limit. So they deprecated this feature.

For details read:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/
- https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=12615

Comment: Yeah I totally didn't even consider just counting the total minus the current results set.  :(

Comment: I am curious is count(ID) faster than count(*)?

Comment: There was a new blog examining that question just the other day: https://www.percona.com/blog/count-vs-countcol-in-mysql/ I recommend subscribing to the percona blog if you want to learn more about MySQL (I worked at Percona 2010-2014).

Comment: Bill, you missed the ultimate question: "determine if there ARE any other rows".

Comment: @CRAIG - I included `COUNT(ID)` discussion in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

(You probably want `OFFSET 0`, not `1`.)

It's simple to test whether there ARE more rows.  Assuming you want 16 rows, use 1 more:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0,17
```

Then programmatically see whether it returned only 16 rows (no more available) or 17 (there ARE more).

Because it is piggybacking on the fetch you are already doing *and* not doing much extra work, it is very efficient.

The second 'page' would use `LIMIT 16, 17`; 3rd: `LIMIT 32,17`, etc.  Each time, you are potentially getting and tossing an extra row.

I discuss this and other tricks where I point out the evils of `OFFSET`:  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

`COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL`.  This is [usually] unnecessary.  The pattern `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(1)`) simply counts rows; the `*` or `1` has no significance.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t` is not free.  It will actually do a full index scan, which is slow for a large table.  `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` are likely to add to that slowness.  `LIMIT` is useless since the result is always 1 row.  (That is, the `LIMIT` is applied to the result, not to the counting.)